# Reducing Java classpath in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm having problems with Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3a when running Java JUnit tests. When trying to launch a test suite with JUnit run configuration, I get the following error:

`Exception occurred executing command line. 
Cannot run program '..java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-1\bin\javaw.exe': 
CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long".`

When I use the same run configuration in Debug mode, the test suite launches without issues. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main), I got the impression that the problem is due to the classpath passed to `javaw.exe` being too long for the Windows command line to handle.

I'm having trouble figuring out where I could check what actually gets added into the classpath in Eclipse. Should I look for the project specific options by right-clicking the project and looking for "Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Source" or from the Eclipse top-bar for "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables"? I was thinking that if I could figure this out, I could maybe try to reduce the classpath.

I would be grateful if someone could point me to the right direction in this issue.